# StructureMap Exception Code: 202

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, structuremap

everyone, I have problems when using MVC3 code is as follows

```
 public SystemController(IRepository repository)
            :this
        (
            repository,
            new AspNetMembershipProviderWrapper(System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider),
                new AspNetMembershipProviderWrapper(System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider),
                new AspNetRoleProviderWrapper(Roles.Provider),
            new SmtpClientProxy(new SmtpClient(Utils.Setting.EmailServer,
                                               int.Parse(Utils.Setting.EmailPort))
                                    {
                                        EnableSsl = true,
                                        UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Utils.Setting.EmailAccount,
                                                                            Utils.Setting.EmailPassword),
                                        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
                                    })
       ){}



        public SystemController(IRepository repository,
            IUserService userService,
            IPasswordService passwordService,
            IRolesService rolesService,
            ISmtpClient smtpClient)
            : base(repository)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            _passwordService = passwordService;
            _rolesService = rolesService;
            _smtpClient = smtpClient;
        }
```

---

```
public class SmtpClientProxy : ISmtpClient
    {
        private readonly SmtpClient _smtpClient;

        public SmtpClientProxy(SmtpClient smtpClient)
        {
            _smtpClient = smtpClient;
        }

        #region ISmtpClient Members

        public void Send(MailMessage mailMessage)
        {
            _smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

---

```
 ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                                 {
                                     x.Scan(scanner =>
                                                {
                                                    scanner.TheCallingAssembly();
                                                    scanner.WithDefaultConventions();
                                                });
                                     x.For<ISessionFactory>()
                                         .Singleton()
                                         .Use(GetSessionFactory());
                                     x.For<ISession>()
                                         .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
                                         .Use(y => y.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());
                                     x.For<IUserService>()
                                         .Use<AspNetMembershipProviderWrapper>();
                                     x.For<IPasswordService>()
                                         .Use<AspNetMembershipProviderWrapper>();
                                     x.For<IPasswordService>()
                                         .Use<AspNetMembershipProviderWrapper>();
                                     x.For<IRolesService>()
                                         .Use<AspNetRoleProviderWrapper>();
                                     x.For<ISmtpClient>()
                                         .Use<SmtpClientProxy>().Ctor<SmtpClient>();
                                     x.For<MembershipProvider>()
                                         .Use(System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider);
                                     x.For<RoleProvider>()
                                       .Use(Roles.Provider);
                                 });
```

---

Error info:

StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

---

I think the problem lies in this:

```
x.For <ISmtpClient> ()
. Use <SmtpClientProxy> (). Ctor <SmtpClient> ();
```

I ask you how to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SmtpClientProxy` class requires an `SmtpClient` class in its constructor.  You don't have anything registered for `SmtpClient`.

Try adding this to your registration:

```
x.For<SmtpClient>().Use<SmtpClient>();
```

This assumes that `SmtpClient` does not take dependencies in *its* constructor.  If it does you will likely get an error that one of its dependencies are not registered with a default implementation.

Alternatively you could change the constructor code to this (no constructor dependency):

```
private readonly SmtpClient _smtpClient = new SmtpClient();  

public SmtpClientProxy()  
{  
}
```

Without knowing what you are trying to do, it's hard to answer definitively.